# string replace exact word in php

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

php

```
$aaa="";
echo $nn="ab bc cd cde ab aa";
echo "<br>";
echo $n=preg_replace('/cd|ab/', '$aaa', $nn);
echo "<br>";
echo $no=preg_replace('/[a-z]/', '$bbb', $n);
echo "<br><br>";
```

The output I was expecting is "$aaa $bbb $aaa $bbb $bbb $bbb".That is when the pattern 'cd' or 'ab' alone is matched it should change to '$aaa' and those unmatched to '$bbb'.

Comment: Unrelated, but still: remove the `echo` from your assignments. This only outputs 1/true.

Comment: cde should be '$bbb' and i want to match exactly 'cd' or 'ab' not cde

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Regex for whole words only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625874/php-regex-for-whole-words-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$aaa="";
echo $nn="ab bc cd cde ab aa";
echo "<br>";
echo $n=preg_replace('/\b(cd|ab)\b/', '$aaa', $nn);
echo "<br>";
echo $no=preg_replace('/((?<= )[a-z]+)\b/', '$bbb', $n);
echo "<br><br>";
```

The first replace matches within: cd or ab within word boundaries (i.e. spaces or start/end of string)

The second replace matches (a-z) 1 or more times, preceded by a space (since $ is also a word boundary). The only downside is that this won't match cde if cde were to be the start of the string.

Comment: This means 'match the string a-z one or more times - but _only_ if it has a space before it. By using this back-assertion it matches what it is supposed to, and doesn't grab the space as part of it.